# TextBoxFor with a thousand separator data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, separator, displayformat

I'd like to get a `TextBoxFor` with a thousand separator.

In an older version of my project, I did it with Javascript

```
$('.thousandSeparator').keyup(function () {
    $(this).val(separator.call($(this).val().split(' ').join(''), ' ', '.'));
});
```

This works, but I don't want to rely on JS and do it only server-side.

So I found :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
```

But this doesn't work.

What I'd like is, ***when the user is typing***, a thousand separator (a space in my case) appears at the 4th, 7th, 10th... number typed in the textbox.

This is supposed to work in a very basic "Create" or "Update" form. However, the `DisplayFormat` data annotation just pre-fill my textbox with `0,00`, but if the user types "1000" I'd like it would be transformed as "1 000".

Is it possible without using JS ?

Comment: No, its not possible without javascript (and you do realize that it would not bind when you submit unless you also create a custom `ModelBinder`)

Comment: Yes I realized it would not bind but I can deal with a custom model binder. But I hoped it was possible without JS, so sad...

Comment: You get the formatted value initially because the html is generated on the server (and uses the format in you `DisplayFormatAttribute`). But your browser knows nothing about c# code running on the server. In order to respond to client side events, you need to use javascript.

Comment: Seems logic... So I'll deal with my JS, thank you :-)